# Access file in Resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring boot application and I want to set the value of one of my parameters (jndi.path) in the application.yml to the path of a file in the resources folder. Depending on the environment, the path is different.

In my application.yml, I have something like this:

---

```
spring:
    profiles: local
    jndi:
        path: file:C/path/to/myRessource/dev
```

```
spring:
    profiles: rct
    jndi:
        path: file:C/path/to/myRessource/rct
```

`dev` and `rct` are folders in the resources folder. The only way this is working is when I set the absolute path.

(Forgive my english)

Comment: how you use jndi.path? Absolutely we should not hard code absolute path.

Comment: this path is needed by a external service my application used. All i have to is set the path!

Comment: If so you can AutoWire Environment object and then set it in code by any value from external services

Answer (score 0):

Create one properties file(config.properties) in resources and give this profile value in this file and use placeholder in yml file like this:

```
profile=rct/dev
```

and in yml file use like this:

```
spring:
profiles: ${profile}
jndi:
    path: file:C/path/to/myRessource/rct
```

and one more change you have to add in yml is to give the details of your properties file, which can be done is this way.

```
    config:
       config-file-path: config.properties
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what i want (my english is bad). I'm going try to explain again. I have two subdirectories ( dev & rct ) in ressources folder. Each subdirectory contain a binding file and the variable jndi.path (in application.yml) value should be the path to binding file. I want know if there is a way to set this path aumatically without specifying the absolute path as the value